# Download large file from Cloud Run via .NET and Next.Js

Tags: .net, next.js, google-cloud-run

I have .NET 6 REST API, running in Docker container and deployed in Google Cloud Run. One of the API endpoints is `DownloadVideo` endpoint that should load and return found video based on `id`.

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadVideo([FromRoute, Required] string id)
    {
        // data are byte[] (or can be a MemoryStream)
        var data = await _service.GetVideoAsync(id);
        if (data is null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        
        return File(data, "application/octet-stream", "video.mp4", enableRangeProcessing: true);
    }
```

On the other side, I have frontend written in Next.JS. I tried several methods, including following serverless function. This function should reach my API and download the video to the client.

```js
import stream from 'stream';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);
const url = 'https://myapi.com/endpoint/1234';

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`unexpected response ${response.statusText}`);

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=video.mp4');
  await pipeline(response.body, res);
};

export default handler;
```

I also tried to use `react-use-downloader`

```
const { download } = useDownloader();
<button onClick={() => download(url, filename)}>Download</button>
```

Even though it works locally, I'm hitting the limits of Google Cloud Run. Based on Documentation
https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas it says `Maximum response size is 32 MiB if not using Transfer-Encoding: chunked or streaming mechanisms`. The average video I'm trying to download via API is 50 MiB, so my application is shutting down and restarting with following error:
`"Response size was too large. Please consider reducing response size."`

I can't figure out which part of the process is not streaming properly. If the API is wrong or the fetching is incorrectly set-up.

Comment: Since the maximum HTTP/1 response size is 32 MiB, you need to add `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` or use other streaming mechanisms. You may check this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.sendchunked?view=net-8.0#examples) for the sample code. You may change the value of `gzip` to `chunked`.

Comment: @RobertG Well, Google docs says that it should be enough to use "streaming mechanisms". I thought that when I use `File()` with stream as an input, it will be streamed from the controller. But apparently, it's not streamed as I thought. I'll look into your example.

Comment: did it work? Do you still get the error message?

Comment: Not really. I went different way and changed completely how file is streamed from the controller.